# How do I start vino-server at boot or login so I can control it remotely?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, vino

I have a server with Xubuntu 11.10, which is gonna be 12 kilometers away (in a factory of my dad's company) in 3 days. So, in 3 days I have to come up with a solution how to administer it remotely. The computer is in the other room for now, so it's easy to go there, login and after that to control it remotely. I installed Vino and made it to start when the session starts. But that means that you have to go, log in and THEN comeback on your laptop and administrate it remotely. So, my question is:

How can I make vino-server to start when Xubuntu is loaded (that means the login screen)? I've done this two years ago on Ubuntu 8.10, but can't remember how.

Comment: Simply add vino server to the Start up applications in Xubuntu

Comment: and then it loads after somebody logs in. I don't need this.

Comment: I had a similar set up working with ssh a while ago. Can't really remember how I did it though...had something to do with the bootstages. However this link might help you. http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot

Comment: Personally I would advise you use ssh with keys, disable passwords. You can forward single applications with ssh -X , and Xming is a X server that will run on Windows from a flash drive. The concern I have with vino is that it is less secure. If you must VNC, take a look at FreeNX (Freenx is both secure and fast).

Answer (score 4):

I was in a similar situation looking for a way to administer some remote Ubuntu servers around the country.

A quick and dirty solution is to have Ubuntu automatically login, have vino in the startup applications, and then set the screensaver to lock in 1 minute.

It's not the most secure method, but all of my servers are running headless in controlled/secure environments so my one minute of exposure is acceptable to solve my dilemma.

The other option would be to not use vino.  Another vnc server like vnc4server can be run from the rc.local and start on bootup.

Comment: how to add vino in startup? what is the command name to be given ?

Comment: In Ubuntu 18 you enable `vino-server` from the GUI "Settings" > "Sharing" > "Screen Sharing".